# How does c++ react to int array indexes while performing standard mathematical expressions?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, int

The idea I have is pretty simple. What I'd like to do is just have the user input a series of integers and plug those integers specified into an array. So for example, here's a segment of the program I'm writing.

```
const int size = 1000;
int array_one[size], array_two[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    std::cin >> array_one[i];
    if (array_one[i] == -1) break;
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    std::cin >> array_two[i];
    if (array_two[i] == -1) break;
}
```

The cut off point is -1. Should the user enter this, one index of the array will be all integers greater than -1 with the following indexes housing 0's in this 1000 sized array. 
What I'm doing next is simply replicating how you would write out basic addition on paper. So, lets say for example I plugged in 1 0 0 6 -1 as inputs for the first array and then 2 3 4 for the second array. The whole entire output should look something akin to this

```
  1006
+  234
------
  1240
```

Here's what I've typed out to get this sort of output

```
int array_size_one = 0;
int array_size_two = 0;
int space_size = 3;
int cut_off_space = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    if (array_one[i] < 0) break;
    array_size_one += 1;
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    if (array_two[i] < 0) break;
    array_size_two += 1;
}

if (array_size_one > array_size_two) space_size += array_size_one;
else if (array_size_two > array_size_one) space_size += array_size_two;

if (array_size_one < array_size_two) cut_off_space += array_size_one;
else if (array_size_two < array_size_one) cut_off_space += array_size_two;

std::cout << std::setw(space_size - array_size_one);
for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
{
    if (array_one[j] < 0) break;
    std::cout << array_one[j];
}

std::cout << "\n+";
std::cout << std::setw((space_size - 1) - array_size_two);
for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
{
    if (array_two[j] < 0) break;
    std::cout << array_two[j];
}

std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(space_size) << " " << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < (space_size - 3); ++i)
{   
    count = array_one[i] + array_two[i];
}
std::cout << count << std::endl;
return 0;
```

This is the part where I think I'm sure I'm having trouble with.

```
std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(space_size) << " " << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < (space_size - 3); ++i)
{   
    count = array_one[i] + array_two[i];
}
std::cout << count << std::endl;
return 0;
```

The idea was that I wanted to add up everything inside each index of the arrays to perform standard integer expressions. The for loop above isn't really cutting it. I'm getting outputs like 5 or 15. If going by the example above that has inputs of 1 0 0 6 -1 for the first array and then 2 3 4 -1 for the second array. What could I actually do inside the very last for loop iteration to make sure I get the correct outputs replicating standard integer expressions?

Comment: Your code is an example of unstructured programming -- programming without functions or stored procedures.  It mixes logic and io, it uses flag values, it abstracts nothing.  Each of these features makes your code harder to understand, debug and fix.  Write a *type* representing your chain of digits.  Have operations on that type, like length, read from stream, strait init, print, etc.  Test each operation.  Write addition without depending on 50 lines of code above, just depending on two instances of your type.

Comment: Is the problem that you are trying to preform addition where each array index represents a tens column?

Comment: *The idea I have is pretty simple.* -- If the issue is the addition, my advice is to drop trying to do fancy output, and instead concentrate on the addition of two numbers.  The latter is far more involved than trying to do fancy output.

Comment: @Mitchel0022 Correct.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree one hundred and ten percent. However, this project has to do with my c++ class. It's not an assignment but some little example over the notes that requires iomanip library. I don't personally think it is necessary at all but that said, it's a requirement of the class to utilize this library and get a full understanding of it.

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. -- If it is an assignment given to you, then you're making the classic beginner mistake when getting assignments like this.  That mistake is wasting most of your allotted time doing the output first, and spending very little to no time on what's important -- the internal calculations, the results, etc, thus you run out of time.  Given two students, one who gets the addition correct and bad output, but the other gets the output right however the addition is nonsensical, who gets the most points?

Comment: There are a couple problems I see, first is you dont account for carrys, second is that you dont account for the tens position of a number when adding it. I recommend what paul said. Forget the iomanip library for now and just work on getting the addition right

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Again. I agree! What bugs me the most about the class I'm taking right now is just that! The calculations are what are important. There's this really annoying problem where instead of actually caring about the calculation, the class... at times... cares about output and making it fancy. Calculations are one thing, I like that. Fancy output... I don't care for. However, we as a class have to care about the output because they're also part of how our grade is for each assignment.

Comment: Figuring out the output formatting is a good challenge and will be good practice, but the addition should be working before you move on. In general when programming tackle each problem one at a time. Divide and conquer.

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. Well as I said, one student hands in fancy output and the wrong answer (maybe they don't even write code to add up the numbers), and another hands in output that shows the two numbers and the correct answer, but one number is skewed to the right or left, or the dashes are off.  Who will get the most credit?  Like I said the addition is far more involved, and that is what you should spend your time on first.  Priorities.

Comment: You could input to a `std::string` and then use `std::stoi` to do the calculation.